# Replace multiple DIV's using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have a jquery script which replaces 1 div with another and replaces 1 link with another when it is selected:

```
$('.child2, a[href="#1"]').hide()

$('#replacepagelinks a').click(function(){
     $(this).hide().siblings().show()
     var w = this.hash.replace('#', '');
     $('#parent div.child'+w).show().siblings().hide()
})
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
   <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
</div>
<div id="replacepagelinks">
     <a href="#1">Replace Child 1 with Child 2</a>
     <a href="#2">Replace Child 2 with Child 1</a>
</div>
```

Please check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KaqZ5/ for a working example.

This works great, however i need it to work with up to 5 divs like so:

1. In child1 i would like only `<a href="#1">Replace Child 1 with Child 2</a>`
2. In child2 i would like `<a href="#2">Replace Child 2 with Child 1</a>` and `<a href="#3">Replace Child 2 with Child 3</a>`
3. In child3 i would like `<a href="#3">Replace Child 3 with Child 2</a>` and `<a href="#4">Replace Child 3 with Child 4</a>`
4. In child4 i would like `<a href="#4">Replace Child 4 with Child 3</a>` and `<a href="#5">Replace Child 4 with Child 5</a>.`
5. In child5 i would like only `<a href="#5">Replace Child 5 with Child 4</a>`

So each page has a 'next' and 'back' link except for the first page which only has a 'next' link and the last page which only has a 'back' link and i need this to support 2 child div's, 3 child div's and 4 child div's as well.

My experience with jquery is almost nil so if somebody can please update my jsfiddle i would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm having a hard time interpreting your intent from the question. It sounds like the user experience that you want is like a navigation, where you can "page" through divs of content, displaying each one in sequence in response to clicking one of the anchor tags. Is that about right? If so, I think your example is unnecessarily complex, and you can optimize it quite a bit. Are you open to changing the structure of the HTML, or is that a fixed requirement?

Comment: No my html is not fixed. I am free to change it around to suit a simpler alternative with new jquery? Thanks @Palpatim

Comment: Looks like your comment did not include a link to how you currently have it, but why don't you update your jsfiddle with 5 elements as you've attempted to get it to work, and we'll can look at what you've tried.

Comment: Here is how i currently have my html set up: http://jsfiddle.net/KaqZ5/4/ Thanks heaps. @Palpatim

Comment: In addition to your demo, post your code within your question.  This needs to remain useful after the demo link goes dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/KaqZ5/7/

**Revised HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu_item">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
            <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
            <div class="child3">Child 3 Contents</div>
            <div class="child4">Child 4 Contents</div>
            <div class="child5">Child 5 Contents</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <a class="prev" href="#">Back</a>
            <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu_item">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
            <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
            <div class="child3">Child 3 Contents</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <a class="prev" href="#">Back</a>
            <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**New CSS**

```
/* Initially hide all menu items */
.parent div {
    display: none;
}

/* Show active item */
.parent div.active {
    display: block;
}

/* If a nav link is disabled, color it grey and set the cursor to an arrow */
a[disabled="disabled"] {
    color: #999;
    cursor: default;
}
```

​**Revised JavaScript**

```
// Set the initial menu state: Each 'prev' link is disabled and the first menu item 
// for each menu block is active
$('a.prev').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.parent div:first-child').addClass('active');

$('a.next').click(function() {
    // Find the parent menu container 
    // - parent of (this) is div.nav
    //   - parent of div.nav is div.menu_item
    var menu = $(this).parent().parent();

    // Find the currently active menu item
    var active = $('.active', menu);

    // Find the next menu item in the list
    var nextItem = active.next();

    // If there is a next menu item, make it active
    if (nextItem.length) {
        // Make current item inactive
        active.removeClass('active');
        // Make new item active
        nextItem.addClass('active');

        // If there's no item after the new item,
        // disable navigation
        if (!nextItem.next().length) {
            $('a.next', menu).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        // If we just clicked 'next', we can enable the 'prev' button
        if ($('a.prev', menu).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
            $('a.prev', menu).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
});

// Pretty much same as above, with the directions reversed
$('a.prev').click(function() {
    var menu = $(this).parent().parent();
    var active = $('.active', menu);
    var prevItem = active.prev();
    if (prevItem.length) {
        active.removeClass('active');
        prevItem.addClass('active');
        if (!prevItem.prev().length) {
            $('a.prev', menu).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        if ($('a.next', menu).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
            $('a.next', menu).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

Here are some important changes I made from your original:

- Use CSS to hide menu items and re-display them using an `.active` class. That makes the markup cleaner, and allows you to style
- Use CSS to visually disable the navigation links, rather than suppressing them altogether. You can of course simply hide them, but if it's truly a user navigation, then you want them to be able to see that the link is simply not applicable, rather than removing it from their view altogether.
- Restructured the navigation to put "Back" before "Next" visually. If you truly want to remove it, you can simply change the CSS definition of the disabled anchors.
- Changed your links to have classes instead of

Some other optimizations you should consider:

- Refactor the guts of the navigation code into a standalone function. It's nearly the same whether you're going forward or backward, so consider making the function more abstract by passing in the parent menu element and a desired direction.
- Use a jQuery pagination plugin, like http://www.xarg.org/2011/09/jquery-pagination-revised/ These have the benefit of greater functionality, and in the case of actively developed plugins, they're likely to be better tested than you'll be able to do on your own.
- You have two navigation blocks on your page, but each of them have `id` attributes which conflict. `id`s must be unique on a page. I changed those to classes instead.
- Consider the case where a menu has one item, or no items. This code will choke on those situations

There are probably a host of other ways to do this, but this should get you started. For futher reading, I recommend perusing the jQuery documentation.

Comment: In addition to your demo, post your code within your answer. This needs to remain useful after the demo link goes dead.

Comment: Wow. You're a genius @Palpatim. Thank you so much for this, it works brilliantly. That must have taken a little while (maybe not? :) ) and i really appreciate it. Just one more thing before you go. How do i incorporate a `return false` into the nav links so that when they are selected the window stays at the same position on the page? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I came up with:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showPage(x){
        $("#parent div").hide();    //hide all pages        
        $('#parent div.child'+x).show();    //then show selected page           
    }
    function showLinks(x){              
        $('#replacepagelinks a').hide(); //hide all links               
        if(x>1)         
            $('#replacepagelinks a#'+(parseInt(x)-1)).show(); //if current page isn't the first one show back link

        $('#replacepagelinks a#'+(parseInt(x)+1)).show();  // show next link
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){                                   
        //$('#replacepagelinks span').on('click',function(e){       
        $(document).on('click', '#replacepagelinks a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();             
            var w = $(this).attr('id');
            showPage(w);
            showLinks(w);                       
        });     
    });
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showPage(1);showLinks(1);">
 <div id="parent">
  <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
  <div class="child3">Child 3 Contents</div>
  <div class="child4">Child 4 Contents</div>
</div>
<div id="replacepagelinks">
 <a href="#1" id="1">page 1</a>
 <a href="#2" id="2">page 2</a>
 <a href="#3" id="3">page 3</a>
 <a href="#4" id="4">page 4</a>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for suggestion on this. You're also a genius coder. :) Pia @Ruben Verschueren